# Can I initialize an object with null?

Tags: c#, null, initialization, initializer

I have an object `Contact`, which is stored on disk.
Upon creating the contact object with `Contact contact = new Contact("1234")` it is automatically beeing loaded from disk:

```
class Contact
{
    public Contact(string id)
    {
        Node? testNode = NodeInterface.FileManager.LoadNode(id);
        if (testNode != null)
        {
            LoadContact((Node) testNode);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Contact does not exist on Disk!"); 
        }
    }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    /* ... */
}
```

now I can initialize a Contact in the following ways:

```
Contact contact1 = new Contact("1234");
Contact nullContact1;
Contact nullContact2 = null;
```

Is it possible to replace the Line in the constructor which throws the Exception with something so that the Outcome is null?

```
Contact nullContact1 = new Contact("thisIdDoesNotExist");
Contact nullContact2 = null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `new Contact` will always result in a `Contact` object being created or an exception thrown. There's no way to cause a constructor to "return" `null`.

You could, however, move this logic to another class and use the Factory design pattern:

```cs
public class ContactFactory
{
    public static CreateContact(string id)
        Node? testNode = NodeInterface.FileManager.LoadNode(id);
        if (testNode != null)
        {
            return new Contact(testNode)
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
}

class Contact
{
    public Contact(Node idNode)
    {
        LoadContact(idNode);
    }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered defining the type as a nullable type? e.g.

`Contact? nullContact2 = null;`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references

Comment: Contact is a class, so what difference would this make? And it still doesn't allow op to initialize the variable with null from inside the constructor.